# PHP OOP how to group configuration data

Tags: php, oop, constants

i wanna store some configuration data in some objects, and i've a problem...

```
class B {
  const attr1 = 'something1';
  const attr2 = 'something2';
  const attr3 = 'something3';
}

class A {
  const attr1 = 'somethingA1';
  const attr2 = 'somethingA2';
  const attr3 = 'somethingA3';
  const b = <---- i wanna put here a reference of B, but B as a class (not an object...), i'm crazy?
}
```

I'm not sure if my example is clear... from A, i want to access to attr1 of B, like A::B::attr1, or something like this, there's another way to do this? Or i'm wrong?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Because the class B contains a group of data of A, i want to store in b (of A) a complex data, i want to do like this because i wanna keep the code clean, i know i could make only the class A with all the attribute...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing but it definitely won't make the code clean ...

Comment: can't you use an array nested with several arrays that group your configs, if you must I guess you could use a singleton of private arrays and provide acessors as appropriate.

Comment: Sry guys for my bad english, btw Tom understand me, its my first lone php project and i want to "group my configuration data" that's the point, and i would use oop to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to assign reference to a Class, nor is there a way to assign class constants at runtime. So your entire approach is pretty much impossible. What you can do is

```
const b = 'B'
```

and as of PHP 5.3.0 you could then do

```
$b = A::b;
echo $b::attr1;
```

but you cannot do `A::b::attr1`. This will raise a `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` error. It's a parser limitation. PHP cannot do this as of this writing.

---

> Because the class B contains a group of data of A, i want to store in b (of A) a complex data, i want to do like this because i wanna keep the code clean

You can solve this easily by [making `B` a composite of `A`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition), e.g. you either [inject `B` into `A`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) when you create `A`

```
class A
{
    private $b;

    public function __construct(B $b)
    {
        $this->b = $b;
    }
}
$a = new A(new B);
```

or [create `B` inside `A`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_%28object-oriented_design%29#Creator), e.g.

```
class A
{
    private $b;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->b = new B;
    }
}
```

Because `B` is just the data parts of `A`, [you tunnel all public access through `A`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) instead of getting hold of `B` and then using B's methods. So any code using `A` does not need to know there is some `B` inside `A`. This will allow you to change `B` easily without needing to worry about code that consumes `A`, e.g. to get `attr1` you add a getter to `A`:

```
public function getAttr1()
{
    $b = $this->b;
    return $b::attr1;
}
```

You can mitigate the clumsy need for assignment when using properties instead of constants in `B` (constants are stupid in PHP anyway as you have to treat them as public API), e.g.

```
class B
{ 
    private $attr1;

    public function getAttr1()
    {
        return $this->attr1;
    }
}
```

And then you can do in `A`:

```
public function getAttr1()
{
    return $this->b->getAttr1();
}
```

Even better would be not to expose the internals of `B` through `A` altogether though and only [add public methods that do something with A](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask). This will make your API much smaller and your code more OO.

Comment: Thx a lot for your huge explanation, i'm already using your second solution (create B inside A), but is not the best solution (because i've to instantiate A but i dont really need instance) in my opinion, but i think that's not another way (yet :P).

Comment: @cl0udw4lk3r if you do OOP, you usually have instances. If you find coding with classes and constants and statics, you are doing class based programming instead. Have a look at http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0103_static_considered_harmful.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reference to a class like that, because the only way you will ever use the class is through an object, so there is no point trying to do that either.

User this:

```
class A {
  const attr1 = 'somethingA1';
  const attr2 = 'somethingA2';
  const attr3 = 'somethingA3';
  public $b;

  function __construct() {
    $this -> b = new b();
}
```

Comment: Yes, but then OP needs to create an instance of A before s/he can access B. And s/he cannot do `A::B::attr1`, nor `$a->b::attr1`. You should add this to your answer to make it complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply say `b = "B"` ..

and if you want to create object of B , You can do  `new b` or access the properties